# Filtrar estados e cidades da biblioteca cidades-estados-js

Tags: javascript

O código abaixo esta funcionando perfeito (usando [cidades-estados-js](https://code.google.com/p/cidades-estados-js/)), gostaria que aparecesse apenas o estado de *Minas Gerais* e *São Paulo*, como faço?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cidades-estados-js.googlecode.com/files/cidades-estados-1.2-utf8.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {

  new dgCidadesEstados({
    estado: document.getElementById('estado'),
    cidade: document.getElementById('cidade'),
     estadoVal: '<%=Request("estado") %>',
     cidadeVal: '<%=Request("cidade") %>'
  });
}
</script>


</head>
<body>    
<form id="sistema" name="sistema" method="post" action="">
<label>Estado</label>
    <select id="estado" name="estado"></select>
    <label>Cidade</label>
    <select id="cidade" name="cidade"></select>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por que você não [apaga os estados que você não quer](http://pastebin.com/Qi2BcFsP)? Isso economiza 60 kB da banda dos seus usuários.

No link em cima tens uma versão onde apaguei os outros estados. Podes copiar e servid o ficheiro do teu servidor. O resultado é este: http://jsfiddle.net/w938st7q/

Comment: Desculpa mas eu não sei como fazer .. estou aprendendo teria como me ajudar ?

Comment: @ALEXBROOK dá uma olhada de novo à resposta. (ctgPi: editei, muda se achares mal, `+1`)

Comment: Ficou excelente era isso mesmo que queria.Sérgio só precisava agora redirecionar o usuário assim que escolhesse a cidade para uma pagina

Answer (score 6):

Sugiro que após executar `dgCidadesEstados`, você pode usar `removeChild`, para isto será necessário dois loops e uma `if`, exemplo:

> **Nota:** recomendo atualizar a biblioteca para [versão 1.4](https://github.com/robertocr/cidades-estados-js) (27/05/2015 - agora é mantida no github) o github e o googlecode não são hosts (cdns) de códigos, recomendo que copie o `.js` para o seu servidor

```js
var estados = document.getElementById('estado');
var cidades = document.getElementById('cidade');
    
cidades.onchange = function()
{
    if (cidades.value !== "") {
        //Para o redirecionamento troque esta linha por window.location
        //veja o exemplo no final da resposta para ter um exemplo
        alert(estados.value + " - " + cidades.value);
    }
};

new dgCidadesEstados({
    estado: estados,
    cidade: cidades,
    estadoVal: '<%=Request("estado") %>',
    cidadeVal: '<%=Request("cidade") %>'
});

var opts = estados.getElementsByTagName("option");
var i = 0, j = opts.length, e, remove = [];

for (; i < j; i++) {
    e = opts[i];
    if (e.value !== "" && e.value !== "MG" && e.value !== "SP") {
        //Pega o elemento que será removido e adiciona ao vetor/array
        remove.push(e);
    }
}

i = 0;
j = remove.length;

for (; i < j; i++) {
    //Remove todos que são diferentes de Minas Gerais, São Paulo e vazio (este ultimo equivale ao "Selecione um estado")
    estados.removeChild(remove[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="//rawgit.com/robertocr/cidades-estados-js/master/cidades-estados-1.4-utf8.js"></script>
<select id="estado"></select>
<select id="cidade"></select>
```

Acaso queira redirecionar após selecionar a cidade, use o evento `change`, como no exemplo o começo do código deve ficar assim (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70297/3635):

```
window.onload = function() {
    var estados = document.getElementById('estado');
    var cidades = document.getElementById('cidade');

    cidades.onchange = function()
    {
        if (cidades.value !== "") {
            //Basta modificar está linha conforme a necessidade
            window.location = "pagina.asp?estado=" + estados.value + "&cidade=" + cidades.value
        }
    };

    new dgCidadesEstados({
        estado: estados,
        cidade: cidades,
        estadoVal: '<%=Request("estado") %>',
        cidadeVal: '<%=Request("cidade") %>'
    });

    var opts = estados.getElementsByTagName("option");
    var i = 0, j = opts.length, e, remove = [];

    for (; i < j; i++) {
        e = opts[i];
        if (e.value !== "" && e.value !== "MG" && e.value !== "SP") {
            //Pega o elemento que será removido e adiciona ao vetor/array
            remove.push(e);
        }
    }

    i = 0;
    j = remove.length;

    for (; i < j; i++) {
        //Remove todos que são diferentes de Minas Gerais, São Paulo e vazio (este ultimo equivale ao "Selecione um estado")
        estados.removeChild(remove[i]);
    }
};
```

Comment: Mas poderia me ajudar Guilherme ? abri outra pergunta.

Comment: Guilherme eu sou muito ruim nisso cara desculpa.. mas precisava de um exemplo real. Devo apagar então new dgCidadesEstados({
    estado: document.getElementById('estado'),
    cidade: document.getElementById('cidade'),
     estadoVal: '<%=Request("estado") %>',
     cidadeVal: '<%=Request("cidade") %>'

Comment: Guilherme eu que peço desculpas, como te disse estou aprendo agora e fiquei muito confuso quando me pediu para usar o removeChild. Usei esse outro código aqui (http://jsfiddle.net/w938st7q/) e me sair melhor. Consegui remover as cidades e inserir manualmente no arquivo.

Comment: Caro Guilherme, somos pessoas leigas buscando conhecimento através de outra que as tem. Desculpe-me  se não pode compreender e ter paciência no que estamos a fazer aqui.

Comment: @ALEXBROOK Eu não estou chateado com a sua falta de conhecimento, estou chateado que lhe forneci um exemplo de **REDIRECIONAMENTO**, você nem disse se ele funcionou ou não, tentei lhe orientar, e você insistiu que o código SÓ removia os estados, mesmo eu explicando que ele também fazia o redirecionamento. Agora se você tive-se dito "Guilherme deu erro tal" ou "Guilherme não está redirecionando", eu teria entendido, mas nem isto você informou. Alex sou uma pessoa legal que só estava tentando lhe ajudar. Apenas isto.