# Como redirecionar o usuário (para outra pagina) após sua escolha?

Tags: javascript

Estou tendo dificuldade de fazer o código abaixo funcionar, preciso que ao ser selecionado uma cidade, este fosse redirecionado para uma determinada página.

Abaixo segue o código que estou tentando usar:

JavaScript:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Qi2BcFsP"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {

  new dgCidadesEstados({
    estado: document.getElementById('estado'),
    cidade: document.getElementById('cidade'),
     estadoVal: '<%=Request("estado") %>',
     cidadeVal: '<%=Request("cidade") %>'
  });
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```lang
</head>
<body>    
<form id="sistema" name="sistema" method="post" action="">
<label>Estado</label>
    <select id="estado" name="estado"></select>
    <label>Cidade</label>
    <select id="cidade" name="cidade"></select>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Alex na minha resposta na outra pergunta não ajudou? Você viu que eu edite ela?

Comment: Tive grande dificuldade. E com este código consegui fácil inserir ou remover as cidades e estados. Não sei onde estou errando.

Comment: Tem dois códigos na resposta é o ultimo, vou postar aqui.

Comment: Com este código aí fiz tudo e deu certinho.. só preciso agora é redirecionar.

Comment: o código lá na resposta faz exatamente isto, rediciona, eu não consigo entender, você não viu a atualização? Tudo bem, segue a resposta com o exemplo de redirecionamento copiado da [outra resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69857/3635). Para testar o código nas respostas clique em **"► Executar trecho de código"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione um evento `change` no seu `select` da cidade, ai tu consegue saber qual o valor.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Qi2BcFsP"></script> 

<form id="sistema" name="sistema" method="post" action="">
<label>Estado</label>
    <select id="estado" name="estado"></select>
    <label>Cidade</label>
    <select id="cidade" name="cidade"></select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {

      new dgCidadesEstados({
        estado: document.getElementById('estado'),
        cidade: document.getElementById('cidade'),
         estadoVal: '<%=Request("estado") %>',
         cidadeVal: '<%=Request("cidade") %>'
      });
  
      document.getElementById('cidade').addEventListener("change", function(){
        var cidadeSelecionada = this.value;
    
        if (cidadeSelecionada && cidadeSelecionada != "Selecione uma cidade") {
           //document.location.href = "suaurl.com?cidade=" + cidadeSelecionada;
           alert(cidadeSelecionada);
        }
      });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Maicon poderia me dar um exemplo com duas cidades abrindo paginas de sites diferentes ?

Comment: @ALEXBROOK Sites diferentes como? Se for mais especifico posso te fazer o exemplo

Comment: Por exemplo: após selecionar a cidade de Divinópolis abre-se a pagina http://redeglobo.com.br/.  Após selecionar a cidade de Belo Horizonte abre-se a pagina: http://google.com.br

Comment: Existe a possibilidade de ser alterado o jeito que é montado o `select`?

Comment: Posso te enviar o arquivo para que possa analisar ? Mas se acessar este link  http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Qi2BcFsP   consegue ver como esta estrutura do arquivo.

Comment: @ALEXBROOK Da uma olhada aqui nesse exemplo que eu fiz: http://jsfiddle.net/h890j0r9/1/

Comment: Basicamente eu adiciono a url no `value` do option e depois só redireciono

Comment: coloquei no script e não deu certo ? poderia inserir no script.

Comment: como você colocou?

Comment: Você realmente está tentando entender o código ou só está copiando e colando?

Comment: Pra entender tu tem que começar pelo "começo" e não pelas soluções prontas

Comment: Vejo que sua dificuldade é na linguagem, não adianta eu te falar como fazer

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4Y7jd4h-T8

Answer (score 1):

Como eu postei na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69857/3635) o exemplo de ***redirecionamento*** e expliquei:

Use o evento `change`, como no exemplo o começo do código deve ficar assim:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var estados = document.getElementById('estado');
    var cidades = document.getElementById('cidade');

    cidades.onchange = function()
    {
        if (cidades.value !== "") {
            //Basta modificar está linha conforme a necessidade
            window.location = "pagina.asp?estado=" + estados.value + "&cidade=" + cidades.value
        }
    };

    new dgCidadesEstados({
        estado: estados,
        cidade: cidades,
        estadoVal: '<%=Request("estado") %>',
        cidadeVal: '<%=Request("cidade") %>'
    });

    var opts = estados.getElementsByTagName("option");
    var i = 0, j = opts.length, e, remove = [];

    for (; i < j; i++) {
        e = opts[i];
        if (e.value !== "" && e.value !== "MG" && e.value !== "SP") {
            //Pega o elemento que será removido e adiciona ao vetor/array
            remove.push(e);
        }
    }

    i = 0;
    j = remove.length;

    for (; i < j; i++) {
        //Remove todos que são diferentes de Minas Gerais, São Paulo e vazio (este ultimo equivale ao "Selecione um estado")
        estados.removeChild(remove[i]);
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cidades-estados-js.googlecode.com/files/cidades-estados-1.2-utf8.js"></script>

<form id="sistema" name="sistema" method="post" action="">
<label for="cidade">Estado</label>
<select id="estado" name="estado"></select>

<label for="cidade">Cidade</label>
<select id="cidade" name="cidade"></select>
</form>
```

Para mudar o endereço de destino basta alterar a linha aonde se encontra `window.location =`