# Como buscar por classe (ao invés de id) em Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, classes

Estou usando um plugin pra popular cidade/estado, mas queria usar em mais de um select, então queria usar por classe ao invés de ID, mas o que tentei até agora não funcionou.

Tentei seguir [esta pergunta famosa do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript), mas não deu certo no script que estou usando:

```
<script>
        window.onload = function() {

            new dgCidadesEstados({
                estado: document.getElementById('estado'),
                cidade: document.getElementById('cidade'),
                estadoVal: '<%=Request("estado") %>',
                cidadeVal: '<%=Request("cidade") %>'
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Com `id` ele funciona certinho, [como dá pra ver nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69802/filtrar-estados-e-cidades-da-biblioteca-cidades-estados-js), mas tentei assim por exemplo `{ estado: document.getElementById('estrec').className = "estado",` e colocando a classe no `select`, mas não deu certo.

Segue um <kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w938st7q/)</kbd> que o @Sergio postou [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69806/23400) (está com apenas dois estados).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma vez que esse plugin espera um elemento de cada vez podes substituir o `getElementById` por `querySelector` tnedo em conta que deves usar `.` para classe e `#` para ID.

Assim o mesmo exemplo com classes seria:

```
new dgCidadesEstados({
    estado: document.querySelector('.estado'),
    cidade: document.querySelector('.cidade'),
    estadoVal: '<%=Request("estado") %>',
    cidadeVal: '<%=Request("cidade") %>'
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w938st7q/1/

Se quiseres aplicar esse plugin a muitos selects basta teres um loop que te passe elementos um a um.

Por exemplo, para este HTML:

```
<form id="sistema" name="sistema" method="post" action="">
    <div>
        <label>Estado</label>
        <select class="estado" name="estado"></select>
        <label>Cidade</label>
        <select class="cidade" name="cidade"></select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Estado</label>
        <select class="estado" name="estado"></select>
        <label>Cidade</label>
        <select class="cidade" name="cidade"></select>
    </div>
</form>
```

podes usar assim:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('form > div');
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        new dgCidadesEstados({
            estado: divs[i].querySelector('.estado'),
            cidade: divs[i].querySelector('.cidade'),
            estadoVal: '<%=Request("estado") %>',
            cidadeVal: '<%=Request("cidade") %>'
        });
    }
}
```

#### jdFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w938st7q/2/

Comment: Oi Sérgio, valeu mais uma vez!  Fiz um teste aqui tirando só o HTML referente da minha página e funciona beleza, mas quando coloco no resto do meu HTMl não funciona... Acho que tem a ver com o loop dos elementos, porque, por exemplo, se incluo uma div vazia a mais no [fiddle que vc postou](http://jsfiddle.net/gustavox/sf3pLza3/4/), ele já não funciona... No meu HTML tem muitos elementos antes destes... a estrutra é tipo container > row > form > col > row > col (cidade/estado) > row > col > row > col (cidade/estado) etc... eu preciso informar toda esta estrutura na `var divs`?

Comment: @gustavox coloca o HTML que tens à volta dos elementos que têm o select que posso dar uma olhada e explicar como usar.

Comment: Então, o HTML é bem grande pra postar inteiro, mas criei um [fiddle reproduzindo a estrutura](http://jsfiddle.net/gustavox/uzqf15mn/1/). O erro que aparece no debug do navegador é `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

Comment: Já marquei como resolvida e dei +1 porque em tese já resolveu, mas ainda preciso de vossa ajuda pra adequar à estrutura do meu HTML... ;)

Comment: Então, fui testando, e no exemplo da estrutura do fiddle que passei funcionou assim: `var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div > div > div > div');` mas acho que não passei a estrutura correta pq no meu HTMl mesmo ainda não funcionou :/, mas acho que já entendi o conceito, to olhando aqui, vai funcionar :-)...

Comment: Então, desta forma funcionou, mas quando coloco a classe da flat-ui (ficando assim: `<select class="select select-primary select-exemploa cidade"  name="Tcid" id="Ccid" data-toggle="select">`) que to usando no select, ele estoura e aparecem as opções fora do select, e o select não aparece... mas acho que isso já é outra pergunta né... :/

Comment: @gustavox pelo HTML do fiddle em cima podes usar `'#Cpost .classdivcol'` -> http://jsfiddle.net/uzqf15mn/2/

Comment: Coloca o HTML dessa "classe da flat-ui" a ver o que é

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25793/discussion-between-gustavox-and-sergio).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso usando jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var elementoDaClasse = $(".nomeDaSuaClasse");
});
```

ou usar o javascript sem dependência dessa forma:

```
var elementoDaClasse = document.getElementsByClassName("nomeDaSuaClasse");
```