# Select de cidades dinâmico , de acordo com o estado selecionado

Tags: javascript

preciso que o select das cidades tenha options de acordo com o estado escolhido.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>estados</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
</head>
<body onload="mods()">

Estado: <select id="estados">
<option></option>
</select><br><br>

Cidade: <select id="cidades">
<option></option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var arrayEstados = ['Rio de Janeiro','São paulo','Minas Gerais']

var rj = {
nome: 'Rio de Janeiro',
cidades: ['Belford Roxo','São joão de meriti','Duque de Caxias'],

} 

var sp = {
nome: 'São paulo',
cidades: ['Diadema','Bauru','Suzano'],

}


var mg = {
nome: 'Minas Gerais',
cidades: ['Belo Horizonte','Betim','Contagem'],

}
</script>
'''
```

Comment: galera sou leigo ainda em javascript, desculpem por não saber explicar de uma forma mais clara. Mas o que eu quero é o mesmo que alguns sites tem. por exemplo, de acordo com o estado escolhido, no outro select aparece apenas as cidades daquele estado.

Comment: Dica: Apresente o seu problema de forma abstrata. Não use diretamente o código com problema. Faça uma versão reduzida, sem sua regra de negócios, sem linhas de código que não estejam diretamente ligadas ao problema. Assim a sua questão fica mais clara para você mesmo elaborar melhor a pergunta, mais clara para outros responderem e mais genérica para ajudar outros no futuro..

Comment: blz amigo vou revisar e editar

Comment: Amigo coloquei só o html e os objetos que devem aparecer nos options. consegue ajudar?

Comment: Amigo, tem um uma pergunta aqui mesmo no stackoverflow que acho que te ajuda. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69802/filtrar-estados-e-cidades-da-biblioteca-cidades-estados-js

Answer (score 1):

Mano eu faria usando um serviço de back End, ai da de salva os idiomas em um banco de dados e usar ajax ex:
o html:

```
    <select asp-for="Estado" id="Estado"aspitems="@(newSelectList(@ViewBag.Origens))">
        <option>Estado</option>
    </select>
    <label asp-for="Estado"></label>
   

    <select asp-for="Cidade" id="Cidade" asp-items="@(new SelectList(string.Empty))">
        <option>Selecione Cidade</option>
    </select>

    <label asp-for="Cidade"></label>
     


    $(function () {
      $('#Estado').change(function () {
            var data = $("#Estado").val();
                     
            $.ajax({
                url: '/endereço do controlador=' + data,
                success: function (data) {
                    var items = "";
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        items += "<option value='" + item.value + "'>" + item.text + "</option>";
                    });
                    $('#Cidade').html(items)
                   
                    
                }
            })
         
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um script simples para responder essa questão. Se surgirem novas dúvidas (é o que espero), faça em novos posts da forma mais objetiva possível, como você fez após a edição.

```js
// Em vez de uma variável para cada estado, o melhor é ter uma estrutura de
// dados unificada. Assim você não precisará de um "if" para cada estado na
// função que alimenta o select de cidades.
var brasil = {
  'Rio de Janeiro': ['Belford Roxo','São joão de meriti','Duque de Caxias'],
  'São paulo':      ['Diadema','Bauru','Suzano'],
  'Minas Gerais':   ['Belo Horizonte','Betim','Contagem']
}

// Adicione os estados no fim do carregamento do DOM.
// Como esse script é o último elemento (e isso é bom), podemos fazer isso
// imediatamente. Se estivesse num arquivo independente carregado no head,
// você poderia esperar por um evento como o DOMContentLoaded.
// https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded
Object.keys(brasil).forEach(estado => {
  let opt = document.createElement('option')
  opt.innerText = estado
  estados.appendChild(opt)
})

// Para atualizar as cidades podemos reagir ao evento de mudança do estado:
estados.addEventListener('change', event => {
  // Limpa o select de cidades:
  while (cidades.firstChild) cidades.removeChild(cidades.firstChild)
  // Pega as cidades do estado selecionado:
  let cidadesArr = brasil[estados.value]
  if (cidadesArr) {
    // Cria o primeiro elemento de valor nulo:
    let opt = document.createElement('option')
    opt.innerText = 'Selecione...'
    opt.value = ''
    cidades.appendChild(opt)
    // Cria uma opção para cada cidade:
    cidadesArr.forEach(cidade => {
      let opt = document.createElement('option')
      opt.innerText = cidade
      cidades.appendChild(opt)
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<!--
Não precisamos renovar o select de estados, então já o deixo com a opção nula.
Colocarei os estados via script, para garantir que os valores sejam idênticos
aos dados.
-->
Estado: <select id="estados">
  <option value="">Selecione...</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<!--
O select de cidades precisará ser reiniciado sempre que o estado mudar, então
não faz sentido nenhuma inicialização aqui no HTML.
-->
Cidade: <select id="cidades"></select>
```